# Photoshop script to delete layer mask of selected layers?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, mask, layer, selected

My main goal is to delete layer masks (without applying - also knowing how to apply before removal would be a nice bonus) from all *selected* Photoshop layers.

Something along the lines of app.activeDocument.activeLayer.removeLayerMask(); would probably get me where I need to be.

I'll take what I can get, so a function of the ScriptListener variety that outputs this kind of code - charIDToTypeID / putEnumerated - would be acceptable, but I'd prefer it to be in actual JavaScript, using the document objects as referenced in the first sentence. Even a solid reference guide that solidly depicts all the functions that can be used on layer masks and/or activeLayers would also be great.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You can get a script to access selected layers [here](https://feedback.photoshop.com/photoshop_family/topics/get_selected_layers_with_photoshop_cc_scripting_api)

Comment: Thanks, @cybernetic.nomad! Hopefully your link will help me refine the code I have that generates a list of, and loops through, selected layers. Now if I can find a simple way to remove layers masks as I'm looping through the selected layers, I think I'll be good to go. :)